# Can malware be contained in an image sent via WhatsApp?

Tags: malware, whatsapp

I went online with a new WhatsApp account earlier (with a new number), and the first thing that happened was that I received a threatening message from a number with an ISD commonly used by scammers and other unsavory figures, that included an image file. Maybe that message was supposed to go to a different number, or perhaps someone else had an account registered to the same number before. I don't know. What I worry about is whether the image in question could have contained anything malicious.

I viewed the image in WhatsApp and in the Android Gallery.

Now, I know, this question gets asked from time to time, but the correct answer changes year to year and I wasn't able to make out one that applies to 2023 beyond commonplace responses like "be careful never to download something from an unknown source" and "it's always possible", so please bear with me. Of course it's always possible, I just want to know whether anything *particular* is known.

Comment: If anything particular is known it will be patched *quickly*. General purpose vulnerabilities in image rendering libraries are ***high profile*** targets, and won't stay unpatched for more than days.

Comment: @vidarlo: "General purpose vulnerabilities in image rendering libraries are high profile targets, and won't stay unpatched for more than days."* - I doubt that this fully reflects the reality. First, such bugs get only fixed after they are known to the vendor which is too often only after they got already exploited for a while. Then they might get patched in the relevant libraries or even the OS, but this does not mean that every affected systems actually receives these patches. Especially with OS level libraries this depends a lot on the update policy of the vendor which is too often lacking.

Comment: Valid point, though it has improved a lot in recent years, across all platforms - including mobile.

Comment: @vidarlo: correct, but at the same time the number of users has increased and thus potential targets for attacks.

Comment: Ahem, should I remind you of LOGOFail and other recent image parsing vulnerabilities which went undiscovered for ages?..

Answer (score 1):

> ... but the correct answer changes year to year

Critical bugs in image libraries still happen and still get exploited as recent vulnerabilities and in the wild exploits with webm have shown. For more see for example [Pegasus spyware and how it exploited a WebP vulnerability](https://www.malwarebytes.com/blog/news/2023/09/pegasus-spyware-and-how-it-exploited-a-webp-vulnerability).